# Mathematical operations within function argument

Tags: function, vhdl

Is it possible to perform mathematical operations within the argument when calling a function?

For example:

```
answer = to_integer(dividend/divisor);
```

Comment: This would take 2 seconds to find out by running it on your simulator. Please do so.

Answer (score 1):

While Phillipe exaggerates the efficiency of the average VHDL coder, it's not a difficult thing to try.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity foo is
end entity;

architecture fum of foo is
    signal dividend:    unsigned (7 downto 0) := ("11111111"); -- 255
    signal divisor:     unsigned (7 downto 0) := ("00001111"); -- 15
    signal answer:      integer;
begin
    process
    begin
        answer <= to_integer(dividend/divisor);
        wait for 0 ns;
        report "answer = " & integer'image(answer);
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

The result:

> foo.vhdl:17:9:@0ns:(report note): answer = 17

The `wait for 0 ns;` allows `answer` to assume the value of the operation (it's a signal, and assignments don't occur when any process is executing or has not yet suspended). For 0 ns will cause a delta cycle delay.

If `answer` were a variable declared in the process it's value would be available immediately and the wait wouldn't be necessary.

The last wait statement without a delay prevents the process from executing repeatedly.